# .htaccess redirection a url to another url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having some problems with the .htaccess file. i want to redirect
read_more.php?pid=2 to vision-mission.php.for this i just try the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^vision-mission-([0-9]+)\.php$ read_more.php?pid=$1
```

then the following error is obtained
Internal Server Error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

please anyone give a solution for this problem

Comment: Can you paste the whole htaccess file and what HTTP Server are you using?

Comment: how about RewriteRule ^vision-mission-([0-9]+)$/.php read_more.php?pid=$1